# ionic FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am running this command in my ionic project

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
k\build-tools\31.0.0-rc5\dx.bat
Build-tool 31.0.0 rc5 is missing DX at C:\Users\daees\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0-rc5\dx.bat

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0-rc5 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\cam\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\cam\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

I did remove and add `31.0.0-rc5\` in my android SDK, but I got the same error

I also followed other threads of stackoverflow, but wasn't able to get the required results.

I also tried removing tools next to version `31.0.0-rc5\` , like `29.xx` etc, but didnt help either

I ran `gradle -v` and I got this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-07-02 12:16:43 UTC
Revision:     774525a055494e0ece39f522ac7ad17498ce032c

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_291 (Oracle Corporation 25.291-b10)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

What do I do ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Within your app go to platform/android/build.gradle and find defaultBuildToolsVersion

ex. defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.2"

Now in android studio go to the SDK manager and download the "Android SDK Build-Tools" version that matches defaultBuildToolsVersion in build.gradle

This worked for me.

Comment: thanks for replying, I did what you said and this time it showed a different error `Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.`

Comment: I have the same error, and the line is already set to 29.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved it by not using the newest build tools, instead opted for 29.0.3 and 30.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Because Android Build Tools 31.0.0 miss dx files. You can check this link for solution

[Android Build Error "Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68844136/16553103)