# Azure DevOps ionic Android Build Error "Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-devops

I recently faced an issue with my Azure CI pipeline when I tried to build apk for Android.

I get the below error:

> Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

**Work Around**: I found a workaround for me when I changed my "cordova-android" version to "8.1.0" from "9.0.0" in package.json file or you can use "ionic cordova add andorid@8.1.0" instead of "ionic cordova add andorid".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happened because `dx` files are missing from Android SDK Build Tools 31.0.0 and replaced with `d8` files. Try to modify Android SDK Build Tools 31.0.0 by:

1. In the Android SDK Build Tools 31.0.0 folder (example: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0`), create a copy of `d8.bat` and rename it to `dx.bat`.
2. In the lib folder, create a copy of `d8.jar` and rename it to `dx.jar`.

Comment: Yes this is a good solution if you are making builds on local machine. The one I proposed helps when you are building on DevOps pipeline.

Comment: This was the fix for me. I'm not sure I understand the DevOps pipeline solution, but being able to do a local build is certainly step one in any good dev process.

Comment: Ah, pardon me @el07 You are right. Perhaps because `cordova-android 9.0.0` drop Travis CI, it'll always search latest Android Build Tools. Meanwhile `cordova-android 8.1.0` still using Travis CI and by default it'll use Android Build Tools 28.0.3.

Comment: But where is the Android SDK Build Tools 31.0.0 folder? Remember that Cordova is for web devs who don't know anything about Android, iOS, etc.

Comment: It depends on your settings @Distortum. If you know your Android SDK location, just find folder build-tools/31.0.0. If you don't know the location, check it in Android Studio or environment settings.

Comment: Another work-around is to downgrade to Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3