# Error:Android Dex: Cannot find file C:\Users\HI

Tags: android

Error:Android Dex: Cannot find file C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\lib\dx.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use another version of Android SDK instead. Google breaks backward compatibility by removing two classes from `dx.jar`. To change the android version just change the line with buildtools in `project.properties` file:

```
(sdk.buildtools=25.0.3)
```

If you really need this library try to copy (example 25.0.3)

```
C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\lib\
```

to the folder

```
C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\lib\
```

You can find similar answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43040723/4977439

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but different version here:

[Azure DevOps ionic Android Build Error "Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68572466/16553103)

This is happened because dx files replaced with d8 files. Modify Android SDK Build Tools 32.0.0 by:

1. In the Android SDK Build Tools 32.0.0 folder (example: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0`), create a copy of `d8.bat` and rename it to `dx.bat`.
2. In the lib folder, create a copy of `d8.jar` and rename it to `dx.jar`.